# How to do mediainfo on m3u8 files

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, ffprobe, mediainfo

My mediainfo CLI  version 19 was working fine until now on single files. But I am really surprised that it is not working with M3u8. It only gives file level information. It is not giving me underlying child M3u8 info and their resolutions etc;

and Just FYI FFMPEG works just fine on m3u8.

Command that I am trying:
mediainfo --Output=JSON http://127.0.0.1:43435/stage-gtp-out-us-east-1/gtp-H264_HLS_profile-1607925602-2d9d45a7-62f9-44c3-b12a-cc4c7f4d0728/ts/master.m3u8

Unfortunately, I cant give access to content. But its standard HLS Manifest. Can somebody help please

Comment: Why not just use ffprobe?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, I cant give access to content. But its standard HLS Manifest. Can somebody help please

Test on some public m3u8 files are fine.
This is a bug report, so it should [be provided to the developers](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/issues), instead of SO, so developers could investigate.
If you can not provide any content, even in private, well you block yourself of the possibility to debug so it will not be fixed.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo.